# Getting the system logs in jelly bean

Tags: android, android-logcat

I've got an app which works fine pretty much most of the time, but I'm finding on occasions stops working.

Is there a way to capture the app and system logs on a rooted phone so I can scan through them afterwards to see where the problem is.

I know about adb logcat > output.txt

but I'm hoping for an "on phone" way to do this so I don't have to have the phone plugged into a computer all the time as it can take a day or two to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this solution will work on Jelly Bean, but it seems to work for OS's prior to JB:

[Access LogCat Data in Your Android](http://androidsnips.blogspot.com/2011/03/access-logcat-data-in-your-android.htm)

The solution uses mainly the exec() method from the Runtime object and requires the READ.LOGS permission. You can then display the output with the correct filter (I'm guessing you'll want to set your filter to either warning or error, as opposed to verbose) using a TextView.